# The dbms output isnt showing the data output?

Tags: sql, oracle

So im suppose to create a procedure that has one input and prints out the paymenttotal and invoicetotal. The procedure is able to compile but its not showing in the output.I know its because the into part because the invoice_total and payment_total are cursors so im trying to figure out where the data is coming from.
Here is my code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE vn_payment(vendorID in number)
IS
payment_total vendors.vendor_id%type;
invoice_total vendors.vendor_id%type;
BEGIN
Select payment_total, invoice_total into payment_total, invoice_total
from vendors
where vendor_id = vendorID;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('payment total:' || payment_total || 'and invoice total'|| 
invoice_total);
END;
```

Comment: Two things: First, did you also RUN the procedure, or just COMPILE it? Compiling it is fine, but you must also run it (common way: `EXECUTE vn_payment(1001)` or whatever you have for vendor ID). Second, you won't see the output if you don't run `set serveroutput on` first. `dbms_output` writes to a buffer, not to the screen. The user interface decides what to do with the data in the buffer. `set serveroutput on` directs the content of the buffer to be displayed on screen.

Comment: lol I did that already and the output was 
"payment total:and invoice total" so I know there some error.

Comment: Can you update your question to make it reproducible?  Include your table definitions, DML to insert some sample data, and the way you're calling the procedure (particularly the values you're passing in for parameters).  It doesn't make sense to me that both local variables are declared as `vendor_id%type` when they appear that they should be `payment_total%type` and `invoice_total%type` but I don't know if that's causing the problem.

Comment: It also doesn't make sense that your local variables are named the same as columns in your table.  That also might not be the issue currently but will cause you problems down the road.  Most people adopt a convention for naming parameters and local variables that ensure they can't conflict with column names.  I prefix parameters with `p_` and local variables with `l_`, for example, which is one common convention.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version. It seems likely your procedure is getting confused because you have multiple things with the same name. Also don't forget to do `set serveroutput on` in sqlplus before running it, but it sounds like you've done that.

1. This adds an alias `v` to the `vendors` table. One this clearly defines where the columns are coming from. Also, if you come back to this procedure in a year and add a `join` to the query, you won't have problems if both tables have a column with the same name.
2. This adds `p_` to the parameter, so it's clear later that it's an input parameter.
3. This adds `l_` to the local variables so it's clear they are local variables.

.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE vn_payment(p_vendorID in number) IS
    l_payment_total vendors.payment_total %type;
    l_invoice_total vendors.invoice_total %type;
BEGIN
    select v.payment_total, v.invoice_total 
      into payment_total, invoice_total
      from vendors v
     where vendor_id = p_vendorID;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('payment total:' || payment_total || 'and invoice total'|| 
invoice_total);
END;
```